# Moving water to elevated destination without pump

Tags: pressure, water

I'm looking for a way to circulate water through a DIY pool heater without a pump. The problem is, the pool heater itself is elevated above the pool, and I don't know of a way to get the water to flow up through the tube without a pump. The only thing I can think of is capillary action, but don't think that that would work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a drawing of your setup and include enough measurements on it to describe what you are dealing with?

Answer (score 0):

A pump is the way go.  Water will flow in a tube if pushed, and pumps are the obvious way to push it.

You can of course use gravity to push it downhill. Water would flow from the heater to the pool. You can make a circulating system where water flows up from the pool to the heater and back down. The need to push water uphill is balanced by gravity's downhill push. If water was flowing in such a system, it would continue for a while until friction stopped it. You need to push it to keep it going.